# JSLint: interperet file as JS code fragment, not JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, minify, jslint

I have my angular clientside javascript broken up such that a controller/filter/service/etc. is contained in its own file. Because I want to minify, I have to use inline dependency injection, so a controller might look like:

```
["$scope", "$aService",
   function ($scope, $aService) {
      // Do something
   }
]
```

The difficulty is that JSLint is reporting errors which I take to mean that it is attempting to interpret the above code as JSON, which it is not -- it is a fragment of javascript. How can I get around this / tell jslint to treat this file as javascript instead?

The specific JSLint Errors:

```
Expected a JSON value. (E003)
Expected ']' and instead saw 'function'. (W116)
Expected '(end)' and instead saw '('. (W116)
```

Comment: I believe that JSLint is complaining because it doesn't think breaking this statement into multiple lines is valid.  That being said, you don't *have* to use inline injection, you can use the `$inject` service.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#!/

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I don't think the line break is relevant, the same errors happen with or without that. The errors are right that function is not valid JSON, but this isn't JSON. `$inject` isn't an option for this as currently structured because the contents of this file are passed to `app.controller` clientside.

Comment: Note that is is workable but not desirable to wrap the code in a self-executing function. I'm really just hoping jslint / jshint is clever enough to have an option to turn off bad filetype guessing

Comment: if that's the whole file, then hint is right; its bad syntax. there's no point in using an array literal around the function like that, and i don't even see how that does anything unless you import the code with ajax and eval() it; loading it as a <script src> won't work, and that's what hint is complaining about.

Comment: I am essentially importing the code with ajax and calling `eval()`, so you're right...